# The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable when updating

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I have some problems when updating my model. This is my update code:

```
public void Update(Class @class)
{
    var updatedClass = context.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassId == @class.ClassId).FirstOrDefault();
    updatedClass.ClassPriceTypeId = @class.ClassPriceTypeId;
    updatedClass.ClassType = @class.ClassType;
    updatedClass.Name = @class.Name;
    updatedClass.Title = @class.Title;
    updatedClass.MetaTag = @class.MetaTag;
    updatedClass.MetaDescription = @class.MetaDescription;
    updatedClass.UrlSafe = @class.UrlSafe;
    updatedClass.Header = @class.Header;
    updatedClass.Margin = @class.Margin;
    updatedClass.ImageName = @class.ImageName;
    updatedClass.GroupId = @class.GroupId;
    updatedClass.IsPublished = @class.IsPublished;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

First problem is that I have made `LazyLoadingEnabled=false` but after fetching `updatedClass` the relational properties like `Group` is not null.

Second problem is that in some of `@class` objects I can easily update my entity but in some others I see this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

**Update**

This is `Class` model:

```
public class Class
{
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int ClassPriceTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MetaTag { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public string UrlSafe { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public int Margin { get; set; }
    public string ClassType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comparing.Model.Price.Price > Prices { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassPriceType.ClassPriceType ClassPriceType { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Garanty> Garanties { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PhoneModel> PhoneModels { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ClassPartner> ClassPartners { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

And this is `Group` model:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MetaTag { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public string UrlSafe { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me about the problem?

Comment: Show the `Class` and `Group` class..

Comment: did you happen to nullify the `Group` property ? try put `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` in the beginning of the method

Comment: I had these lines in my context:
base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
base.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
But its not working yet.

Comment: the only cause that I can think of is its a proxy and somehow the `Group` is set to null, if the proxy is disabled, this should be solved, where do you put the configuration? on parameterless constructor ? or there is another constructor ?

Comment: The configuration is in my Context class constructor.

Comment: You need to enable lazy loading as your collections are set to virtual. If you want to use eager loading remove virtual and use .include in linq queries.

Comment: @dellywheel No. It didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to update a primary key field which is having a relation ship with other foreign key with not null constraint. I guess you need to use update cascade.

Comment: I guess it will successful, if you do not update the primary key value.

Comment: I pass the old primary key in a Html.HiddenFor(model=>mode.ClassId) when I am updating a @class object. I dont change the primary and its auto increment.

Comment: is there chance to groupId going null?

Comment: No. GroupId and other keys are not going null at all!